# Data for a view in SpringMVC from Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a problem to get information from a query in hibernate. In my class dao, have a function like this.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getOcurrencesPerMonth(){
        List<String> dataOcurrences = (List<String>) getHibernateTemplate().execute (new HibernateCallback() {
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
                Query query = session.createQuery("select concat(year(ror.created),'/',month(ror.created)), dt.name, count(distinct ror.id) from RawOccurrenceRecord ror, DataProvider dt" +
                        " where ror.dataProviderId = dt.id" +
                        " group by month(ror.created),ror.dataProviderId");
                return query.list();
            }
        });

    ArrayList<String> dataO = new ArrayList<String>();  

    Iterator<String> iterator = dataOcurrences.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        dataO.add(iterator.next());
    }

    return dataO;
}
```

I pass the List to the view, and use a c:forEach in the jsp for view the result, but i only have results like Ljava.lang.Object;@1659f66

My query in MySQL is

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(raw_occurrence_record.created),'/',MONTH(raw_occurrence_record.created)), data_provider.name, COUNT(DISTINCT raw_occurrence_record.id) FROM raw_occurrence_record, data_provider WHERE raw_occurrence_record.data_provider_id = data_provider.id GROUP BY month(raw_occurrence_record.created), raw_occurrence_record.data_provider_id;
```

And the result is like

```
2012/12 | POL | 15
2013/1  | JKL | 45
2013/1  | GTK | 30
```

¿How i do to get data for each column in the query in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your query doesn't return a `List<String>`, it returns a `List<Object[]>`.  `[Ljava.lang.Object;@65690726` is what you get when you call toString() on an Array, which ultimately your JSP is doing when you try to print it.

You want something like this (although architecturally speaking one wouldn't generally do this in a class called *-DAO!)

```
for (Object[] result: dataOccurences) {
  data0.add(result[0].toString() + "|" + result[1].toString() + "|" + result[2].toString());
}
```